# Make an element move by hovering over another element

Tags: html, css, hover

I would like to hide the `nav` element totally from the user. When the user hovers over an icon (in this case, an image), the `nav` element should slide in from the top of the screen. I thought about a countdown of 0.5 seconds before the animation starts, then 1 second when the `nav` element moves from its initial position (above the screen) to its final position (at the top of the screen). The `nav` bar should stay there until the user stops hovering over the icon or the `nav` bar.

The problem is that my `nav` element appears in its final position when the icon is hovered - it does not move as it should do. From tests I've done so far, it seems that I cannot move an element when hovering over another, but I hope I'm wrong and that it's possible - I explored an option but it ran the animation in a loop and I could only get it working once, nor moving from location A to location B as it was moving from A to B to A. I tried using margins, paddings, changing height, I browsed many topics from here and other websites, but I could not find a way, probably because my code is a mess. I am learning JS so I am open to all solutions.

Here is my code, as cleaned as possible:

```
    <header>
        <div class="thing">
            <img src="img/mainicon.png" class="mainicon">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Half-Life</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Half-Life 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Half-Life Alyx</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="clean"></div>
    </header>
```

```
.mainicon {
    width: 8%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    float: left;
}

.mainicon:hover + nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

nav:hover {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.clean{
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

nav {
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 4px solid #2CBCD6;
    background-color: grey;
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 25px;
}

a {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: 0.625%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than you think. Don't complicate it for yourself.

In short, all you need to do is set the `margin-top` to something negative to hide it and then `margin-top` to `0` when hovering over the image or the menu.

Here is a demonstration:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.thing {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.mainicon {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 10;
  left: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  background-color: bisque;
}
.mainicon:hover + nav,
nav:hover {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

nav {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  margin-top: -60px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
}

a {
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="thing">
    <img
      src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/heroicons-ui/24/menu-512.png"
      class="mainicon"
    />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Half-Life</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Half-Life 2</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Half-Life Alyx</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header
```